# How can I recreate the image gallery animation as shown in Google Zeitgeist 2013 ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

The [Google zeitgeist 2013](http://www.google.com/trends/topcharts?zg=full&hl=en&utm_source=google&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=nye) page displays a regular image grid, and it repeats in both horizontal and vertical mouse drag movement. It looks amazing!

Is there an existing js open project does the same as Google zeitgeist 2013?

Comment: check what js files are being used on the page in your browsers development tools

Comment: Check my answer, it might put you into some direction :)

Answer (score 2):

I think they are using CSS transforms to achieve this. Have a look at this short .gif animation that I have captured while moving browsing the Zeitgeist page, can you note how the transform property is changing the values dynamically. I am of the opinion that it's CSS based but there is JS playing its part, probably.

[image]

I also inspected their 4 JS files and they all seem to be either Angular JS or Prototype libraries, and there's seems to JS involved in there too, if you note the selector `js-detail--searches_grid` It's a custom solution by Google though, so I am not aware of any similar implementation, but if you put enough time studying its working, i.e. reverse engineering, you can create one too.

I have done some more investigation into this and it turns out it is using CSS `transform matrix`, which you can look [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/). It's a complicated thing to understand at first, but very rewarding. The matrix method take six parameters, containing mathematic functions, which allows you to: rotate, scale, move (translate), and skew elements. This is evident from the code used by Google (see the 6 parameters in the image I've supplied).